# ETL SSIS - Package taking too long when starting another step

Tags: ssis, etl

I'm having some trouble to diagnose this situation.
In short, when I'm going to the next step, it will only start after a very long time (as you can see in the image below).

[image: ETL]

Anyone has any tips that I might investigate further?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get a better idea of exactly where the delays are, try implementing logging on the objects causing the slow-downs.  Specifically, log the `PipelineComponentTime` event, which indicates how long each component take within a particularity phase.  If you're wanting to track the time between when a task stops and the next starts, try looking at this event for the `PrimeOutput` and `PostExecute` phases of the first task, and the `PreExecute` and `ProcessInput`, and phases and the subsequent component.  Without looking at your package, I'd suspect that the majority of the time is being spent in the `PrimeOutput` phase and you'll want to focus on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Steps of execution are these:
1- pre-execution
2- execution
3- post-execution

Those time you have highlighted are the moments when the pre-execution and post-execution has been started.
so it seems it took 2mins to **run your whole package**
and it is not just from one step going to another.
I wish this answer helps

Comment: Thank you for the information but did you check the image? The time that is starting the other step?

Comment: it took more than 2 hours, that's what made me worried

Comment: I dont understand why there is no execution time between pre and post. but I am searching that why this could happen @SérgioRebelo

Comment: one of the things that happens during pre execute is to cache lookup tables if you have lookup component in your package so this can take time

Comment: other options like MaxBufferRows and DelayValidation can be effective too

Comment: I think i will test my queries on both steps to see if anything is wrong